# arithmetic series - solving problem

Tags: arithmetic

I don't understand this question.

The 10th organ is 4 times bigger than the 3rd organ.
The amount of all 50 organs together is 3725.

Find D and a1.

How can I solve that? I have absolutely no way.

Comment: What are D and a1 ? How many organs are identical ? I think we do not have all the information here. Thanks to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Do you know if $a_1,D$ be the first term & the common difference respectively,

$n$th term $=a_1+(n-1)D$

Sum of $n$ terms  $\displaystyle=\frac n2\{2a_1+(n-1)D\}$

So, you will have two equations with two unknowns

Reference : [Arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Assuming the organs are in arithmetic progression in size, the size of organ $n$ is $a_1+d(n-1)$  Now plug in what you are given:  $a_1+9d=4(a_1+2d), 50a_1+\frac 12(49)(50)d=3725$.  Two equations, two unknowns.